# PowerApps Filter Gallery with DatePicker

Tags: filter, datepicker, gallery, powerapps

Trying to add a filter to a gallery based on datepicker from a sql datasource. The date format is YYYY-mm-dd.

When I add a filter to the a SQL datasource gallery and I add a datepicker to allow me to filter the records on date.   SQL displays the date as YYYY-MM-dd.  Datepicker is showing date as MM\dd\YYYY.   When I enter a date that I know I have data for, no data is display.  I don't get an error in the formula.

**Formula for Gallery.items:**

```
Filter(
    vw_Expenses, 
    Date = dp_ViewExpensesDateFilter.SelectedDate
)
```

Nothing is displayed.  Is it because SQL displays dates as YYYY-MM-dd?  If so, how do I fix this?  If not, what is the recommended change to get the filter working on my gallery?

Comment: I found this solution on a forum, but something is wrong with my syntax, any help here: Filter(vw_Expenses,DateValue(Text(Date, "en-US")) = DateValue(Text(dp_ViewExpensesDateFilter.SelectedDate, "en-US")))  Here is where I got this solution: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Filter-using-date-field-from-SQL-Server/td-p/149691

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type on the SQL column. It could be text or `DATE`, etc.

The DatePicker control in PowerApps is of `Date` type:

[image]

- Notice the `, 12:00:00 AM` appended

By rapping it in the `Text()` Function, you can change it to `Text`:

[image]

You need to match up the DataSource (SQL) and the PowerApps data types to get the Filter function to work.